# Automatic file deletion based on file age

Tags: windows

Does anyone know of a good way to delete files based on their age and have it done periodically, say using a batch file and windows scheduler?  (Or any other decent software that would do this as well)

Comment: You already answered your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

+1 for 'forfiles"

here's what I use in a batch file that runs nightly:

forfiles -pE:\myfolder\mysubfolder -m*.* -d-5 -c"cmd /C del /q @FILE"

Comment: Perfect - this is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [forfiles commnad](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551(WS.10).aspx). Just use the windows scheduler to schedule it directly.

[Some more examples](http://winhlp.com/node/180).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've got one we use.  Found it online and made some modifications to it.

This would be run as

> deletefiles.bat 5 C:\Temp *.LOG 1

and would delete all the log files in C:\Temp and its subdirectories more than 5 days old

Ah, found the [original post](http://mihirshah.wordpress.com/dos-techniques/)

```
@echo off

CLS
:HouseKeeping
REM Start Time
REM This will load the current time into 'Start' variables.
REM.
Set Start_Time=%time%
FOR /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:." %%a in ('echo %time%') do (
set Start_hh=%%a
set Start_mm=%%b
set Start_ss=%%c
)

FOR /f "tokens=1-3 delims=: " %%a in ('time /t') do (set Start_Meridan=%%c)
Echo Start Time: %Start_hh%:%Start_mm%:%Start_ss% %Start_Meridan%
REM Echo Start Time: %Start_hh%:%Start_mm%:%Start_ss%

Set Delete_Counter=0
Set FChecked_Counter=0
Set Total_Files=0
Set Finish_day=0
SET OLDERTHAN=%1
SET FileDir=%~2
SET EXT=%3
SET Sub_Dir=%4
SET Force_Check=%5
IF NOT DEFINED OLDERTHAN GOTO SYNTAX
IF NOT DEFINED FileDir GOTO SYNTAX
IF NOT DEFINED EXT GOTO SYNTAX
IF NOT DEFINED Force_Check Goto Get_Date
IF DEFINED Force_Check Goto Read_Only
Goto Exit

:Read_Only
IF %Force_Check%==1 set Force_Delete=/F
Goto Get_Date

REM Get Todays Date
:Get_Date
FOR /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/- " %%a in ('date /t') do (
set xx=%%a
set mm=%%b
set dd=%%c
set yyyy=%%d
)

set /A mm=%mm%+0
if %dd%==01 set dd=1
if %dd%==02 set dd=2
if %dd%==03 set dd=3
if %dd%==04 set dd=4
if %dd%==05 set dd=5
if %dd%==06 set dd=6
if %dd%==07 set dd=7
if %dd%==08 set dd=8
if %dd%==09 set dd=9
set /A dd=%dd%+0
set /A dd=%dd% - %OLDERTHAN%
set /A yyyy=%yyyy%+0
:LOOPDATE

if /I %dd% GTR 0 Goto DONE
set /A mm=%mm% - 1
if /I %mm% GTR 0 Goto ADJUSTDAY
set /A mm=12
set /A yyyy=%yyyy% - 1
:ADJUSTDAY
if %mm%==1 Goto SET31
if %mm%==2 Goto LEAPCHK
if %mm%==3 Goto SET31
if %mm%==4 Goto SET30
if %mm%==5 Goto SET31
if %mm%==6 Goto SET30
if %mm%==7 Goto SET31
if %mm%==8 Goto SET31
if %mm%==9 Goto SET30
if %mm%==10 Goto SET31
if %mm%==11 Goto SET30
if %mm%==12 Goto SET31
:SET31
set /A dd=31 + %dd%
Goto LOOPDATE

:SET30
set /A dd=30 + %dd%
Goto LOOPDATE

:LEAPCHK
set /A tt=%yyyy% %% 4
if not %tt%==0 Goto SET28
set /A tt=%yyyy% %% 100
if not %tt%==0 Goto SET29
set /A tt=%yyyy% %% 400
if %tt%==0 Goto SET29

:SET28
set /A dd=28 + %dd%
Goto LOOPDATE

:SET29
set /A dd=29 + %dd%

:DONE
if /i %dd% LSS 10 set dd=0%dd%
rem if /I %mm% LSS 10 set mm=0%mm%

:Search_Type
IF NOT DEFINED Sub_Dir GOTO No_Sub_Dir
If %Sub_Dir%==0 Goto :No_Sub_Dir
If %Sub_Dir%==1 Goto :Sub_Directory
Else Goto :No_Sub_Dir

:No_Sub_Dir
for %%i in (%FileDir%\%EXT%) do (
set FileName=%%i
call :PROCESSFILE %%~ti)

Goto Print_Results

:Sub_Directory
for /R %FileDir% %%i in (%EXT%) DO (
set FileName=%%i
call :PROCESSFILE %%~ti)
Goto Print_Results

:Print_Results
Echo.
Echo The number of files deleted : %Delete_Counter%
Echo.
Echo The number of files passed over : %FChecked_Counter%
Echo.
Echo The Total number of files processed: %Total_Files%
Echo.
Goto Get_Finish_Time

:Get_Finish_Time
REM This will load the current time into 'Finish' variables.
REM.
FOR /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:." %%a in ('echo %time%') do (
set Finish_hh=%%a
set Finish_mm=%%b
set Finish_ss=%%c
)
FOR /f "tokens=1-3 delims=: " %%a in ('time /t') do (set Finish_Meridan=%%c)
Goto Calculate_Time

:Calculate_Time
REM Calculate the difference in time between Start and Finish times
REM.

IF %Start_ss% GTR %Finish_ss% (
set /A Finish_ss=%Finish_ss%+60
set /A Finish_mm=%Finish_mm%-1
)
set /A Diff_ss=%Finish_ss%-%Start_ss%

IF %Start_mm% GTR %Finish_mm% (
set /A Finish_mm=%Finish_mm%+60
set /A Finish_hh=%Finish_hh%-1
)
set /A Diff_mm=%Finish_mm%-%Start_mm%

IF %Start_hh% GTR %Finish_hh% (
set /A Finish_hh=%Finish_hh%+24
set Finish_day=1
)
set /A Diff_hh=%Finish_hh%-%Start_hh%

REM The follow will adjust for negative time values.
REM.
REM if %Diff_hh% LSS 0 (set /A Diff_hh=%Diff_hh%+23)
REM if %Diff_mm% LSS 0 (set /A Diff_mm=%Diff_mm%+59)
REM if %Diff_ss% LSS 0 (set /A Diff_ss=%Diff_ss%+59)
REM The following will compensate for single digit results.
REM.
if %Diff_hh%==0 set Diff_hh=00
if %Diff_hh%==1 set Diff_hh=01
if %Diff_hh%==2 set Diff_hh=02
if %Diff_hh%==3 set Diff_hh=03
if %Diff_hh%==4 set Diff_hh=04
if %Diff_hh%==5 set Diff_hh=05
if %Diff_hh%==6 set Diff_hh=06
if %Diff_hh%==7 set Diff_hh=07
if %Diff_hh%==8 set Diff_hh=08
if %Diff_hh%==9 set Diff_hh=09
if %Diff_mm%==0 set Diff_mm=00
if %Diff_mm%==1 set Diff_mm=01
if %Diff_mm%==2 set Diff_mm=02
if %Diff_mm%==3 set Diff_mm=03
if %Diff_mm%==4 set Diff_mm=04
if %Diff_mm%==5 set Diff_mm=05
if %Diff_mm%==6 set Diff_mm=06
if %Diff_mm%==7 set Diff_mm=07
if %Diff_mm%==8 set Diff_mm=08
if %Diff_mm%==9 set Diff_mm=09
if %Diff_ss%==0 set Diff_ss=00
if %Diff_ss%==1 set Diff_ss=01
if %Diff_ss%==2 set Diff_ss=02
if %Diff_ss%==3 set Diff_ss=03
if %Diff_ss%==4 set Diff_ss=04
if %Diff_ss%==5 set Diff_ss=05
if %Diff_ss%==6 set Diff_ss=06
if %Diff_ss%==7 set Diff_ss=07
if %Diff_ss%==8 set Diff_ss=08
if %Diff_ss%==9 set Diff_ss=09
Goto Print_Time

:Print_Time
REM This will return the results to the user.
REM.
Set End_Time=%time%
Echo.
Echo The program started at: %Start_Time% %Start_Meridan%
Echo The program ended at : %End_Time% %Finish_Meridan%
Echo hh:mm:ss.mm
Echo.
Echo This is the amount of time elapsed from the
Echo start to the end of the program executing.
Echo.
Echo %Diff_hh%:%Diff_mm%:%Diff_ss%
Echo hh:mm:ss
Echo. Number of Days Elapsed: %Finish_day%

Goto Reset_Variables

:Reset_Variables

REM The following will reset the variables used by this program.
REM A.K.A. cleaning up.
set mm=
set yyyy=
set dd=
set thedate=
set xx=
set tt=
set FileDir=
set FileName=
set ext=
set OlderThan=
set Sub_Dir=
set Delete_Counter=
set Total_Files=
set FChecked_Counter=
set Force_Check=
set Force_Delete=
set Diff_hh=
set Diff_mm=
set Diff_ss=
set Start_hh=
set Start_mm=
set Start_ss=
set Start_Meridan=
set Finish_hh=
set Finish_mm=
set Finish_ss=
set Finish_Meridan=
set mm=
set hh=
set ss=
set Start_Time=
set End_Time=
set Finish_day=
Goto Exit


GOTO Exit

:PROCESSFILE
set temp=%1
set fyyyy=%temp:~6%

if /I %fyyyy% LSS 100 set fyyyy=20%fyyyy%
if /I %fyyyy% GTR 2069 set fyyyy=19%temp:~6%

set fmm=%temp:~0,2%
set fdd=%temp:~3,2%

:: +*************************************+
:: | This is where the files are deleted |
:: | Change the DIR command to DEL to |
:: | delete. DIR is used for test. |
:: +*************************************+

if /I %yyyy%/%mm%/%dd% GEQ %fyyyy%/%fmm%/%fdd% (
rem Echo %yyyy%/%mm%/%dd% "- The selected file will be deleted.  F: " %fyyyy%/%fmm%/%fdd% %FileName% >> files.txt
echo %FileName% >> d:\deletelog%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd%.txt
del %FileName% >> d:\deletelog%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd%.txt
rem Dir %Force_Delete% "%FileName%"
Set /A Delete_Counter=%Delete_Counter%+1
Set /A Total_Files=%Total_Files%+1
Echo.
) Else (
rem Echo %yyyy%/%mm%/%dd% " - The selected file does not qualify for deletion. F: " %fyyyy%/%fmm%/%fdd% %FileName%  "%FileName%" >> files.txt
Set /A FChecked_Counter=%FChecked_Counter%+1
Set /A Total_Files=%Total_Files%+1
Echo.) 

set temp=
set fyyyy=
set fmm=
set fdd=

:EXIT
```

Comment: OMG, that's one of the longest scripts that I have seen in a the longest time that does something that you can do with a single command  ;-)  ServerFault should introduce an award for this kind of post... this script almost make calculating 5+5 using one's fingers seem high-tech!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Powershell script you can use in a scheduled task.  (Also used this in [**this answer**](https://serverfault.com/questions/65329/how-can-i-keep-iis-log-files-cleaned-up-regularly/65348#65348) for purging IIS log files).

```
set-location [enter-path-to-folder]
foreach ($File in get-childitem) {
   if ($File.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)) {
      del $File
   }
}
```

Change the folder path to your target, tweak AddDays as appropriate.  -30 removes things older than 30 days.