# Equivalent of forfiles.exe in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

sorry if this is asked before but, I was curious about what is the equivalent Linux command of [forfiles.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551%28WS.10%29.aspx) in Windows? This came to my mind when I saw [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/66698/automatic-file-deletion-based-on-file-age) question

Comment: If you included a description of exactly what forfiles.exe does, those of us who know Linux very well will find helping you much easier.

Comment: sorry, It's my bad not to explain what forfiles.exe does in windows; but a simple google search gives satisfying results on what forfiles.exe does. Anyway, I'm still ashamed of myself why "find" didn't come to my mind before asking this silly questions ;)

Comment: @MikeyB, you could have followed the link to the other question.  There was a forefiles description there.  I updated the question to include a link directly to the technet docs.

Answer (score 4):

`find` is the full-powered replacement, but for simple operations on files in the current directory this `sh`-script can be pretty useful (and easier to read/write) as well:

```
for file in *.jpg; do
  echo "do something with $file"
done
```

Comment: You could have spelled it "for files" ;-) [I know, then it wouldn't make sense.]

Answer (score 3):

The [**find**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command does what you want. Here's an example:

```
find /mnt/Pictures -name '*.jpg' -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
```

This will delete all the jpg files from `/mnt/Pictures`, which have not been modified in the last 7 days (168 hours) or more. If you don't care about the case of the filenames use `-iname` instead of `-name`.

Here's a correspondence between the parameters of *forfiles* and the parameters of *find*:

- `/p` → the path is the first argument of find.
- `/s` → by default find searches in all subdirectories. To disable this use the [`-maxdepth`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Directories.html#index-_002dmaxdepth) option with a value of 1, i.e. `-maxdepth 1`.
- `/c` → [`-exec`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Single-File.html#index-_002dexec). Also replace `@file` with `{}` and don't forget to end the command with `\;` (many beginners are bit by this error).
- `/d` → [`-mtime n`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Age-Ranges.html#index-_002dmtime). File's data was last modified *n**24 hours ago; use `+n` for greater than *n* and `-n` for less than than *n*.

In case you need to negate a condition, use [`!`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Combining-Primaries-With-Operators.html#index-_0021). Because `!` is a special character under some shells, including Bash, it needs to be escaped or quoted, therefore you'll write `\!` most of the time.

Comment: What does the `\!` flag after `-name` do?

Comment: Your use of -mtime doesn't seem to match the documentation you linked to. You say that `\! -mtime 7` gives files that have not been modified within 7 days. But I think it should actually give all files that were not last modified exactly 7 days ago. It seems from the documentation that what you should want is `-mtime +7`.

Comment: @AndrewRay well, it's ambiguous :-) If you want exactly 7 days, `!` is the way to go. If you want 7 days or more, `+7` is the way to go. Anyway, your made a good point, so I've edited my answer to make it more clear and perhaps more useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) provides the functionality that forfiles offers.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for reminding ;)

I searched google a little bit and I think this should be the answer:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/delete-files-older-than-x-days-on-linux/

Answer (score -4):

You can create a cron job that uses find with the appropriate arguments, e.g. -mtime +7

Comment: What does cron have to do with forfiles?