# Secure file transfer to transfer files to clients

Tags: file-transfer, security

Today, our company is using an FTP Server to transfer files to clients, vendors and more.

Now, we want something more secure.

**Needs**

- Uploading with FTP (Windows Explorer, no own program), Browser (IE 7 / 8) or similar
- Download with any suitable browser (IE 7 - 9, FF 3 - 4, ...)
- Download with encryptet connection (SSL, ...)
- automatic deletion of old files (for example with a token which is only 2 days valid)
- *no* directory listing for other files, ...
- not *too* expensive ;-)

Thank you very much

Comment: After some looking around, I don't think Windows Explorer supports SFTP/FTPS. That's your first problem ;)

Comment: Are you looking for a web app where your clients can log in and access their files?

Comment: Yes, that's my big problem :) I think, the best would be a web app where co-workers can upload the file and get a https-link which they can send to clients. And they should configure a period of time in which the file is valid to download. A bit like Rapidshare ;-)

Comment: (the web app should have a LDAP Auth or similar)

Answer (score 0):

IIS 7.5 (Server 2008) supports an FTPS server; however, IE and FF don't without plugins, you'd have to get client software.

I think you're on the right track ... upload with FTP, and make available via HTTPS for download, that way browser and plugins don't affect the client end.

You could use the directory listing option in IIS but that's ugly and wouldn't meet your selective enumeration needs. What about something like [one of these](http://www.hotscripts.com/category/php/scripts-programs/file-manipulation/upload-systems/)?

Comment: Hi- thank you for your answer. with the IIS, i sadly can't get an "unique download link" and an expire date or something like this and the most of this scripts don't have ldap auth - and because it's in the DMZ, the script has to be good and secure.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think I'd be much help. You've got some steep requirements that are a good bit beyond what I'm used to dealing with ^_^; You could run something separate for the file scavenging ... http://serverfault.com/questions/66698/automatic-file-deletion-based-on-file-age covers that.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at OpenVPN ALS (http://sourceforge.net/projects/openvpn-als/). The technology has been gobbled up by Barracuda Networks who now offer it both as a software package and appliance.

Comment: Thank you. Sadly, that would be too much for sharing files. It should be easy for the end-user to download files, he shouldn't have to logg in install browser-addons (like juniper, ...) just for downloading a file :)

Comment: Actually, if you take a closer look, no add-ons are needed! The Java-based VPN portion is actually more "hype" that practically in most cases anyway.

Answer (score 0):

We send files to clients using [Basecamp](http://basecamphq.com/signup)—a web-based project collaboration tool. For $49/mo, you get 35 projects and 15GB of storage. We chose this solution because we needed to track milestones and actions in addition to being able to share files with clients.

While this is a very different approach from hosting your own ftp server, which is what we did previously, we have found this to be a cost-effective and client-friendly solution. Clients receive an email with instructions for logging into the [Basecamp](http://basecamphq.com/signup) project that we've invited them to, and then they can download files at will.

**Disclaimer:** I am not an employee of, or compensated, by 37signals—the creator of [Basecamp](http://basecamphq.com/signup).

Comment: Our company has about 2000 user and like to have all sensitive data on our own storage, so Basecamp is not a good soloution for us, thanks anyway!

Comment: @Xarem: I'd recommend adding this information to your original question as an additional requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like the University of Delaware's Drop Box.

https://turin.nss.udel.edu/wiki/dropbox/doku.php

Comment: Not useful since it doesn't appear you can download the source and host it yourself...

Comment: Yes, you can, it's been open sourced.

Comment: A link to said source would be useful, then.

Comment: It's called Google.  Use it.   https://turin.nss.udel.edu/wiki/dropbox/doku.php